# Sum number on every click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple problem but I really dont remember how to solve it, maybe my brain is playing with me, however, here is my problem... I have a product price, I'm adding this price to a `var total`, the problem is that I want to sum the result of my code to the first result stored on total var. For example:

> First click: total = 0, price = 32, after click total = 32.
>
> Second click: total = 32, price = 100, after click total = 132.

How can I do this? This is my example code:

```js
var total = 0;
var price = 16;

$('#btn').click(function () {
  var qty = $('#qty').val();
  
  var total = qty * price;
  
  alert(total.toFixed(2));
  
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="btn">Click</button>

<input id="qty" placeholder="Type the number of products u want..." />
```

Comment: You are declaring the variable outside the method, and again inside. Remove the var inside the click.

Comment: `total += qty * price` and remove `var` before it resolve your problem

Comment: @PanamaProphet that´s it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got `var total` inside your function which is creating a separate local variable. Remove the `var` so that it uses the global variable.

Also, you weren't adding the 2nd value to the running total. You were just overriding total over and over.

```js
var total = 0;
var price = 16;

$('#btn').click(function () {
  var qty = $('#qty').val();
  
  total = total + (qty * price);
  
  alert(total.toFixed(2));
  
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="btn">Click</button>

<input id="qty" placeholder="Type the number of products u want..." />
```